# Link in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one link -> About.. when I click appears information for instance about me, but I want when user click on link called "about" appears instead of "about" "Home" (index.html.erb). How possible i can do it? JavaScript? or without? maybe with `<% if ... %` ?

Ty!

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're asking, please post some code. It sounds like you simply need to change to the `href` attribute of your link from `/about` to `/`.

Comment: ehhh i dont really understand your question. Do you mean something like this? `<%= link_to "home", path_name %>` ??

Answer (score 1):

in routes.rb:

`root :to => "home#index"`

In your view:

`<%= link_to("About", root_path)%>`